# How can I know which of my dependencies is using a dependency that is causing a warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, sockjs

In my browser console I am getting

```
index.js:126 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings    @   index.js:126
(anonymous) @   socket.js:47
sock.onmessage  @   SockJSClient.js:67
EventTarget.dispatchEvent   @   sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @   sockjs.js:891
SockJS._transportMessage    @   sockjs.js:889
EventEmitter.emit   @   sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @   sockjs.js:2965
```

The word "sock" is nowhere in my package.json, so I figure one of my dependencies requires sockjs, and that if I update this dependency the warning will go away.

I figure it's probably axios, but how can I know for sure, or how can I search through my dependencies to see what requires sockjs?

Comment: you could check for 'sockjs' in your package-lock.json as it maintains the dependencies of all the packages used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yarn has a very useful commands for such things: `yarn why <name_of_dependency>`. If you're more into npm, you can use `npm ls` to generate the dependency tree of your project instead and search manually.